# MongoDB query only works with copy and paste

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having a peculiar problem with MongoDB where when I try to make a query on the database, like `db.departments.find({"key": "MEL 301"`}), there are no results found.

I'm currently using mLab to host my MongoDB database, so there is a way to visually see the documents in the collections. When I locate the document that has the key `MEL 301`, and I copy and paste `MEL 301` into its respective spot in the query above, the query then succeeds and finds the document. To clarify, only when I copy/paste the key value from the database into the query instead of typing it out does the query work.

You can test out the database with this shell command (username is `stack` and password is `overflow`): `mongo ds015335.mlab.com:15335/utcourses -u stack -p overflow`

After testing out some key value, not just `MEL 301`, you might find something like this – the first query was where I typed out `MEL 301` and the second query was where I copy/pasted the value from the database itself.

[image]

Comment: then you have something wonky in there, like an invisible/unprintable character that happens to be preserved by the cut/paste operation. e.g. `MEL&nbsp;301` instead of `MEL[actual space]301`

Comment: @MarcB That's what I was initially thinking, but I can't seem to figure out how to solve it. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: @Shrey I don't have permissions to your database :) `Error: error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on app.departments", "code" : 13 }`

Comment: Am I using the wrong db?

Comment: pull out the record (match on some other field?) and then inspect the key field and see what's in there, e.g. convert it to hex values and look for weird stuff.

Comment: @JoshBeam Hm, that's weird. What was the query you performed?

Comment: @MarcB No copy/paste: `4d454c20333031`, Copy/paste: `4d454ca0333031`. Looks like the `2` in the first is `a` in the second.

Comment: @Shrey I did `db.departments.find({"key": "MEL 301"})`

Comment: 4d = `M`, 45 = `E`, 4c = `L`, a0 = ? , 33 = `3`, 30 = `0`, 31 = `1`, so you don't have plain ascii in there, and your "space" is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented - it did turn out to be an encoding error. I decided to make a small utility function in order to solve this problem. The non-breaking spaces would be converted into regular spaces, and this is tested and working on MongoDB and mLab.

```
exports.fixSpace = function(string) {
  var fixed = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    string.charCodeAt(i) === 160 ? fixed += ' ' : fixed += string[i];
  }
  return fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, when you converted each to hexadecimal, here's the output:

Copying and pasting: `4d 45 4c a0 33 30 31` (focus on the `a0` here, that's the problem)

Without copying and pasting: `4d 45 4c 20 33 30 31` (`20` is whenever you hit the space bar on your keyboard)

`20` is the actual whitespace character that you get whenever you hit the spacebar on your computer (you can see from [this table](http://ascii.cl/) that `20` hex value resolves to the symbol `space`).

`a0` is tricky. It's actually a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), which is *not* the same as a `space` symbol, and in fact doesn't have an ASCII code. **That's why when you type `MEL 301`, you're hitting the space bar on your keyboard and inputting the `20` hex that resolves to a space, but the "space" inside the document is stored as a non-breaking space**.

The problem is that your value is `MEL` + a non-breaking space character + `301`.

Here's the table of encodings for that `a0` (from the above non-breaking space link):

[image]

It seems there was some problem with the original encoding of the data when it was imported into your database.